# To whom is "The Lotus Caves" (John Christopher) dedicated?

Tags: john-christopher

Looking through my copy of "[The Lotus Caves](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?13184)" by [John Christopher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Christopher) (one of the pseudonyms of Samuel Youd), I noticed that is was dedicated:

> To Julia
>
> for the spark that broke the log-jam

Do we know who Julia was? The book was published in 1969, and at the time Christopher was married to Joyce Fairbairn, so it doesn't apply to her, nor does it match with any of his children's names.

user23087 noted in comments that their copy of "The Lotus Caves" was dedicated:

> To Susan, for flying to the rescue

I've looked through the different versions available at the Internet Archive, and it appears that the American editions (Aladdin and Collier House) were dedicated to Julia, while the British editions (Heinemann and Penguin/Puffin) were dedicated to Susan. This adds another name to the mystery! From the preface to "The White Mountains" I know that Susan Hirschman was Christopher's American editor. Possibly Susan and Julia were the American and British editors respectively (although in that case it is odd that it was Susan acknowledged in the British editions and vice-versa). I would be interested to know.

---

Like Youd, [Eric Frank Russell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_Frank_Russell) was a member of the Fortean Society. Despite the occasional [spat](https://www.joshuablubuhs.com/blog/sam-youd-and-joyce-fairbairn-as-a-fortean) they remained friends and frequently wrote to each other. Many of Russell's papers are archived at the University of Liverpool, and it is interesting to see mention of this [letter](https://sca-archives.liverpool.ac.uk/Record/92612)

> EFR/3/2/17 - Typescript letter from Sam Youd, Sussex - Aug-Oct 1965
>
> Youd describes a visit to Harry Harrison's First World SF Pro
> Conference; and his (Youd's) problems with a "barren period in
> writing”.

The "barren period" may well correspond to the "log-jam" mentioned in the dedication. It would be interesting to see Youd said, and if he mentioned how the log-jam broke.

---

I further noticed that "Wild Jack", published in 1974 (5 years after "The Lotus Caves") is also dedicated to a Julia, namely "Wild Julia". Could they be the same person?

Comment: If we think of the creative process as a fire, then spouses and children tend to be less like sparks and more like drizzle or pouring rain. My guess is that Julia was a science-fiction person: writer, editor, publisher, agent, or fan.

Comment: @user14111 That's a little bit of a cruel observation ;)  but I wanted to eliminate the obvious candidates first. Julia sounds like a significant person, so I'd hope she is mentioned in an interview or biography

Comment: His obit mention two wives and fivechildren.  No Julias.

Comment: And there's always the possibility that he gave his "muse" a pseudonym.

Comment: I agree the most likely is his editor or his agent.

Comment: @GordonD Do we know the names of his editor or agent at the time?

Comment: Oddly my copy of "The Lotus Caves" has a different dedication.  This is a British Puffin edition.  The latest reprint date listed is 1986.  The dedication reads "To Susan, for flying to the rescue".  I have no more idea who Susan is than Julia...

Comment: @user23087 Thanks for noticing this. I've added the information to the question

Comment: The "Wild Julia" seems like something I wondered about when I was a kid, but I don't think I ever resolved the question.

Answer (score 7):

After considerable searching I am cautiously optimistic that the identities of the two dedications, Julia and Susan, can be identified.

A very useful source was an biography of Christopher in the July 1981 edition of the children's book magazine "[Books For Keeps](https://booksforkeeps.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/BfK-9-July-1981-optimized.pdf)". From this we learn:

> It was as an established writer that he was approached by Hamish
> Hamilton to write a science fiction novel for children.

This novel must surely be “The Lotus Caves”. And the editor for children’s fiction at Hamish Hamilton at this time was one [**Julia Macrae**](https://www.womeninpublishinghistory.org.uk/content/category/interviewees/julia-macrae).

> He at first turned down the idea, mainly because he didn't like the
> idea of being commissioned to write a novel. Another problem was that
> his teenage passion for science fiction had cooled. He found the past
> by now more stimulating than the future as an incentive to the
> imagination.

So it seems that Hamish Hamilton had to coax him into writing it, which probably accounts for the second part of the dedication “for the spark that broke the log-jam”.

The second name, “Susan” is easier to place. Having identified “Julia” as being his British editor it seems natural to look to his American editor, and she was indeed named “Susan”, **S[usan Hirschman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Susan_Hirschman)**. I first came across her name in the preface of “The White Mountains”. Christopher told:

> So I wrote The White Mountains and sent it off. The London publisher
> approved of it. Another copy went to New York. My agent there wrote
> back to say he had offered the book to a children's book publisher, who
> had turned it down but said they might be interested if I rewrote it.
> He enclosed a long letter from the children's books editor.

The editor insisted that several parts of the book should be redrafted. Fuming, Christopher did it, and later realized that her judgement was absolutely correct.

> My editor in New York was Susan Hirschman. The original version of The
> White Mountains was probably just about worth publishing: the London
> editor thought so. But would it. without Susan, have remained in print
> and worthy of a commemorative relaunch, three and a half decades after
> its original publication? I’ve no doubt about the answer to that.
>
> I was to learn a hard but invaluable lesson: there’s no such thing as
> a “mere children’s book,” and children’s book editors are some of the
> brightest and most dedicated people in the field.

Comment: A fantastic piece of sleuthing. You have my +1